# PayumBundle Paypal Express confirmation step

Tags: paypal, payum

Is it possible to perform a custom action, such as checking a date, in payment confirm? I want that just after click the confirmation button do a query to database and depending on result confirm the payment to paypal or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. you have to overwrite the [confirm order action](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Action/Api/ConfirmOrderAction.php).

You can pass your own to [the factory](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/PaypalExpressCheckoutGatewayFactory.php#L64).

```
<?php
$factory->create([
    'payum.action.api.confirm_order' => new AcmeConfirmOrderAction(), 
]);
```

If you are using symfony, register the action as service and add the tag:

```
acme_configrm_order_action:
   class: AcmeConfirmOrderAction
   tags:
       - { name: payum.action, alias: payum.action.api.confirm_order, factory: paypal_express_checkout_nvp }
```

I've not tested the code but it should be something like this. You can test it works with console command: `app/console payum:gateway:debug`

Comment: But, how to use this on the Symfony Payum Bundle? Where can I pass my own confirm order action?